# Running custom python scripts across a network from one server

Tags: python

Is it possible to access python scripts from a server in network and each user has the 'init.py' with the following code where the network path is added including his own python folder in his '.nuke' folder?

```
nuke.pluginAddPath ('./python')
nuke.pluginAddPath ('./gizmos')
nuke.pluginAddPath ('./tcl')
nuke.pluginAddPath ('./icons')

nuke.pluginAppendPath('\\\\server\\Nuke Plugin\\scripts')
```

The above did not work for me. What am I missing here?

Comment: This Depends, wether you are on Linux/Mac/Windows, if you are running the script as an admin, its easier.

Comment: Its Windows machine. And the server where the scripts are located is shared across the network.

Comment: Your questions answer is == YES! But this is as trivial as storing files an an usb stick. What do you really want?

Comment: When I tried doing the above it didn't work. So just wanted to make it work.